# Accessing discord API with requests python results in 401: Unauthorized

Tags: python, python-requests, discord

I wanted to make a script that on authorization, pulls my alt onto the server on discord.

Using requests + flask I tried to make a PUT request which ended with 401 Unauthorized

```py
# Oauth.discord_api_url = "https://discord.com/api"
# at = Access token (it works)
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {at}"}
guildid = *insert id here*
urlguildy = f"{Oauth.discord_api_url}/guilds/{guildid}/members/{userid}"
r = requests.put(url=urlguildy, headers=headers).json() # 401 Unauthorized
```

I had the other command that shows guild list and it worked just fine, but this just returns 401. I'll be glad if someone helps.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by using BOT TOKEN as a header and ACCESS TOKEN as a json parameter. So it grabs the application bot on the server and does some authorization things. Piece of code:

```
        endpoint = f"{Oauth.discord_api_url}/guilds/{guildid}/members/{userid}"
        bot_token = "yes"
        botheader = {"Authorization": f"Bot {bot_token}", "Content-Type": "application/json"}
        payload = {"access_token": access_token}
        r = requests.put(url=endpoint, headers=botheader, json=payload).json()
```

(its in the function that i am going to use)